# "Infinity" as a tattoo

Tags: word-choice, words, meaning

I know this is really "Mainstream", but let's say I would like to have the word "infinity" as a tatto.

[image]

(edit)

4.

[image]

Which one would be the right ? And what exactly does each of them mean ?

Comment: Actually, if you really want one of those words as a tattoo, I don't recommend you to show your first picture to your tattooist, on the calligraphic viewpoint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 無限 = infinity.
- 永久 = eternity.
- 常: rarely used as a standalone noun. It's something like *ever-* in *evergreen*, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. where do you have the information from ? And what does the word mean that I've edited in my question ?

Comment: @Ace naruto is a native speaker of Japanese...

Comment: 永遠 is also eternity. I'm a native Japanese speaker.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. So to close it up, it wouldn't be strange for people who understand japanese language to read that word as a tattoo, would it ? I just want to be shure that it would be the same, as if I would read the english word "infinity" instead.

Comment: 無限 is not a stupid word at all. But [I can't say that tattoo will be appreciated positively](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3631) by ordinary Japanese, either.